# How do I format a csv file (such as omitting first row and column) without modules?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have imported a csv file and want to format it by removing the first row and the first two columns so I can then perform calculations on the data. I also need to display the csv values in a list of lists and convert to float.

I can not find any assistance that does not involved the use of modules (such as import csv or panda). How would I do this without modules?

This is all I have so far

```
for i in inFile:
    listRows = i.strip().split(",") # Converts to list
```

Displays my data in a list of lists, but I have no clue what to do next without using a module.

Comment: why do you want to do that? Csv parsing is HARD, don't reinvent that

Comment: try to use read_csv from pandas

Comment: Can you show us some of the data and the output you want?

Answer (score 1):

Pandas is a heavy piece of software, but the `csv` module in included in the Python Standard Library, so you *really* should wonder why you should not use it.

But it is possible to parse *by hand* a csv file, provided it is trivially formatted with no corner case like multi line fields.

Your sample data can be parsed with:

```
with open(csvfile) as fd:
    _ = next(fd)   # skip first line
    # parse what remains as float skipping first field
    lst = [[float(i) if i.strip() != '' else None for i in line.split(',')[1:]]
        for line in fd]
```

Comment: @Electric_Sheep01: It should thanks to `i.strip() != '' else None` but has not been tested.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Christian Sauer mentioned, why reinvent. It is easier to use the CSV package. 
But if you insist you can get try something like below

```
>>> d = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
>>> d
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
>>> [x[1:] for x in d[1:]]
[[5, 6], [8, 9]]
```